# Laravel get route parameter from request instance

Tags: laravel, request

I have a route

```
Route::get('/category/{categorySlug}', 'CategoryController@showPage')->name('category.show');
```

Is it possible to get categorySlug from $request instance? I mean $request->get('categorySlug') Cause I dont see that param in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the parameter using route in request:

```
 $request->route('parameter_name')
```

in this case:

```
 $request->route('categorySlug')
```

and you can get all parameters as array:

```
$request->route()->parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `categorySlug` in method like as below :

```
public function showPage($categorySlug){
    // use $categorySlug here
}
```

Comment: I need it from request. Like $request->route('categorySlug')

Comment: Okay.Yes you can do it like that way.But generally i pass the slug as a parameter to use and if you also want to use Request instance then you can pass your slug as a second parameter.

Comment: The problem is to send parameter via few level of methods call manually. I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

- **Qutestion :** Is it possible to get `categorySlug` from `$request` instance? I mean `$request->get('categorySlug')`
- **Answer :** yes you can `$request->get` means you need to send data via `get` method which is like this

`example.com?getKey=getdata` here you can get `getdata` via `$request->get('getKey')`

### Conclution

```php
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@showPage')->name('category.show');
```

and send slug via `example.com/category?categorySlug=slugdata` then it will work

else if you want to work with old code like

```php
Route::get('/category/{categorySlug}', 'CategoryController@showPage')->name('category.show');
```

then no need to pass any get param laravel can handel `categorySlug` by

```php
public function showPage($categorySlug){ // you will get `categorySlug` as parameter
    // use $categorySlug here
}
```

or by `$request->route('categorySlug')`  this also you can access

Comment: I meant $request->route('categorySlug') or $request->route()->hasParameter('categorySlug')